# How to schedule .Net console application on Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks

I am completly new to AWS.

We need our console application to start once a day on Amazon Web Services. Do anybody know where to find information on how it can be done? Does AWS provide any kind of email-report-on-error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon doesn't have the ability to host and run a console application for you directly.

The basic steps to do it yourself would be:

1. Setup a Windows server instance on Amazon EC2.
2. Install your console application on your new server.
3. Setup a job in Task Scheduler to run you console application.

Note: YOU are responsible for administering, updating, and monitoring your job on your EC2 server.  Amazon is just renting you a server... nothing more...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And, if somebody is reading this thread: using EC2 instanse to host scheduled job means that this instance should always run, which is not good if you are paying for machine time.